# Mapping Unit Tests to methods

Tags: c#, unit-testing

We're using Microsoft's Unit Test program and we use the Unit Test Wizard to create one-to-one mapping for methods in each class from the business layer. The issue is the amount of work needed go through and determine if we are missing any tests after the initial tests were created.

Currently I have to run the wizard and look for tests that have a "1" appended to the default name [method][test]. Those with that name mean we have already have a test for that method. The ones without an append 1 mean those are methods that don't have a Unit Test that follow the default naming convention.

I'm wondering if there is away to map Unit Test to a method with attribute on the Method so it doesn't take as much work. And yes, I know if we were following TDD we would write the Unit Test first. We write the test in parallel to development (but sometimes in rush it is missed).

Comment: Check out NCrunch or NCover or dotCover.  The cost of it should end up being less than (Josh's per hour salary * time).

Comment: Are you just writing one unit test per method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio 2012 and have the appropriate version, it has proper code coverage analysis built in: "Run tests with code coverage".

Otherwise, you can use a diagnostic tool to run code coverage, such as NCover. You can do this from inside Visual Studio using [TestDriven.net](http://www.testdriven.net/)

Comment: We are still on VS2010. I'll check out TestDrivent.